# Changing other installed app icons from your Xamarin app [Android]

Tags: android, xamarin, icons

I'm trying to make an icon pack using Xamarin but the problem is I don't know where to start . 
There are templates for an icon pack app using eclipse but I want to make my icon pack app using Xamarin !

So the problem is I don't know how to change icons of other packages using Xamarin , I know that the launcher should support custom icons/Icon packs !

There are tons of icon packs on Play Store , usable in most major launcher applications , How can I do that on Xamarin ?

I can't find any code on how to change other app icons

Comment: `icon pack` is designed for a specific launcher application. There are no universal icon packs.

Comment: Sure, But lots of icon packs in Play Store are compatible with major launchers like Nova , Apex etc . I just don't know how to do it in Xamarin

Comment: Nova and Apex are made on similar basis. And they support custom icon packs. You should specify which launcher you are targeting in your question. And I think that it is totally bad idea to make a 100% android-targetted app on cross-platform SDK.